# Price is not showing up on the registration page after Joomla to Wordpress integration

Tags: wordpress, civievent, registration, price-sets, online-registration

So I'm moving my site from Joomla! to Wordpress, and I need to move my CiviCRM database and everything related to it. I did manage to do that by installing the same version of CiviCRM on Wordpress as the one i was using on Joomla(4.7.14) and than copying the civicrm database. All the data is there, all the pages, all good. The only thing I have issues with is the Price(Fee) field, it is not showing up on the Registration pages for some reason. I added some screenshots how it looks like on frontend and backend.

Any help you can provide would be more than welcome, thank you in advance!

[image: Place where price should be shown]

[image: How it looks in backend]

[image: Error i get after trying to register for event]

Comment: Was this event active in your Joomla site with a Price field or are you creating a new event since migrating to WP?

Comment: i would try doing a comparison in your database for the joomla v wp and confirm if the data in the relevant tables match - and of course flush civicrm caches for good measure

Comment: I did try all of that already and did not work unfortunately. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I'd try upgrading Civi to a more more recent version.

If that does not fix it, I'd look for a plugin/theme conflict. Disable all plugins except Civi and try it. If it works, start enabling plugins until it fails again. If it still does not work, try a basic WP twenty-something theme and see if it works.